# ag-grid rowgroup row color for the entire row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have ag-grid-enterprise which has rowGroup enabled,

I want to color the full row when there is a rowgroup created.

Can anyone help me on this.

[image]

I want it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using pure css. In your styling file

```css
.ag-row-group.ag-row-level-0 {
  background-color: #f0ffff;
}

.ag-row-group.ag-row-level-1 {
  background-color: #faebd7;
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Row Group Full Row Color]